# golang test assert the test is failing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I am writing several helper functions for tests that I would like to test.

I need to make sure that in some conditions the test function will fail the test. Since this is the expected behavior - my actual test needs to succeed.

Some ideas of how I can achieve this? Something like test reset or fake testing.T object.

Comment: Your test function should return an error in the conditions where the test function "should fail the test", then check for that error?

Comment: @AlexanderKohler Thanks, yes, this is one way to do it, but it is not very convenient since I already have a lot of helper functions that operate on the test object directly and the more complex ones depend on other.

Comment: @AlexanderKohler also propagating the failure to the end will complicate the triaging of issues - "hiding" the origin of the problem.

Comment: any sample code for your `Testcases`